# Using jQuery to Animate a circle border right to left

Tags: jquery, css

In the following html hierarchy `.counter-box` is a circle drawn with `border-radius`:

```
<div class="counter-box">
     <div class="result photos"><span class="count">14</span><span><br>Photos</span></div>
     <div class="result reduce"><span class="count">32</span>%<span><br>Smaller</span></div>
     <div class="result size"><span class="count">92</span>MB<span><br>Saving</span></div>
</div>
```

I want use jQuery function to animate counting from to zero to reach of the 3 numbers and to draw a border. the thing is all should happen in the same duration. i managed to get the three numbers to work together using the following simple jQuery :

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

But i'm still getting trouble drawing the circle's border. Any idea what can i use inside the `animate` function to draw a border from right to left in a way it will finish drawing same moment numbers finished the counting? here's [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fe6h39o/3/#) to present the boarder "after drawn"

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.counter-box {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #16c7f3 inset;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FF;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 35px 22px; */
  margin: auto;
}

.count {
  display: inline-block;
}

span.unit {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.result {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 100%;
}

.result.photos,
.result.reduce {
  padding: 30px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie">
  <div class="counter-box">
    <div class="result photos"><span class="count">14</span><span><br>Photos</span></div>
    <div class="result reduce"><span class="count">32</span>%<span><br>Smaller</span></div>
    <div class="result size"><span class="count">92</span>MB<span><br>Saving</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0fe6h39o/13/) is something that i done using a [plugin](https://github.com/akzhy/radialProgress) that i created. The plugin still has some bugs, you can either do the same process that the plugin uses or try other solutions (eg: SVG)

Comment: Thanks @Akshay ! looking good, the only thing i'm missing here is some smoothness, any lead to where i might be able to work on it in the plugin code?

Comment: The plugin doesn't handle the animation by itself, instead it is the setInterval method that handles the animation, try changing the value of `filled+= 5` to other values (100 should be divisible by that number)

Comment: Changing the interval time to `10` and `filled+=1` seems to give a smooth and nice effect [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0fe6h39o/16/)